# Does * in (<*>) have a special meaning?

Tags: haskell, operators, naming-conventions, applicative, category-theory

Trying to expand my understanding about symbols in Haskell :

- `($)` : Function Application operator (Allow you to apply arguments over a function)
- `(&)` : flipped version of Function Application Operator? `(&) = flip ($)`
- `(<>)` : associative operator (You'll find it in Semigroups and Monoids)
- `(<$>)` : function application `($)` lifted over a Functor structure
- `(<&>)` : flipped functor map

Can we make a link between `(*)` and `(<*>)`?

I don't understand the meaning of `*` actually...

Comment: I don't think there is a link between `*` and `<*>`, I guess `<*>` was chosen for its relation to `<$>`, but I'd say the `*` used here is quite arbitrary.

Comment: I don't think the `*` in `<*>` is meaningful. Function names `<$>` and `<&>` are clearly taken from `$` and `&`. However, `<*>` is incidental. I think the `<` and `>` were chosen so that the idiom `f <$> x <*> y <*> z` looks nice, but the `*` looks arbitrary there.

Comment: @chi do you have historical notes on that? I don't know for sure whether this was deliberate, but to me the reference to the products in monoidal functors is striking and seems unlikely to be a coincidence.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Mine is only a guess, I have nothing to back me up. I don't know if I agree with you on this point: I would if we had `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a,b)`. Just because this can be defined in terms of `<*>` is not enough to fully convince me. (But you might be right!)

Comment: @chi see edit to my answer: it **is** derived from products in the original McBride and Paterson paper.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is deliberate. `<*>` has characteristics of a [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). This is best seen in the list monad:

```
Prelude> (,) <$> ['a'..'e'] <*> [0..4]
[('a',0),('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('a',4)
,('b',0),('b',1),('b',2),('b',3),('b',4)
,('c',0),('c',1),('c',2),('c',3),('c',4)
,('d',0),('d',1),('d',2),('d',3),('d',4)
,('e',0),('e',1),('e',2),('e',3),('e',4)]
```

More generally, applicative functors (aka [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor)) map from the product of two objects (i.e. product type, aka tuple or via currying *two function arguments*) behind the functor to the functor-result of a product before the functor. So it's a pretty product-ey operation indeed.

*φ*<sub>*A*,*B*</sub>: *F A* ∙ *F B* → *F*(*A*⊗*B*)

...in Haskell,

```
φ :: (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)
φ = uncurry (liftA2 (,))
-- recall `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`
```

or even

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
type x ⊗ y = (x,y)

φ :: f a ⊗ f b -> f (a⊗b)
```

To see the historical side, look into [McBride and Paterson 2008](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) (doi:[10.1017/S0956796807006326](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796807006326)), the paper that first introduced the `Applicative` typeclass. They note

> The Applicative class features the asymmetrical operation `⊛`, but there is an equivalent symmetrical definition.
>
> ```
> class Functor f -> Monoidal f where
>     unit :: f ()
>     (★) :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
> ```
>
> These operations are clearly definable for any Applicative functor...

So, the `<*>` is an ASCII rendition of McBride and Paterson's `⊛` operator, which in turn is an “applicativised” form of `★` which the category theorists call, in uncurried form, φ.

Comment: great ! Thank you !