# meaning of `<>` in this family `<*>,<$>,<&>`

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions, category-theory, monoids

I'm Trying to expand my understanding about symbols in Haskell :

```
 $  : Function Application operator (Allow you to apply arguments over a function)
 &  : flipped version of Function Application Operator? (&) = flip ($)
<>  : associative operator (You'll find it in Semigroups and Monoids)
<$> : function application ($) lifted over a Functor structure
<&> : flipped functor map
<*> : applicative operator
```

Can we make a link between `<>` and this family `<*>,<$>,<&>`? I made a quick conclusion when only looking at `<*>,<$>,<&>` that `<..>` was related to something over a structure, but then what is the link between structure and associative operator ?

Comment: I think it's best to think of `<>` as being unrelated to other `<...>` operators. (But maybe there's some connection I can't see)

Comment: I think it's a bit of a tongue-in-cheek reference to the idea that `<...>` itself is some sort of operator on other operators. If you think that `<x>` performs some sort of common lifting operation on an operator `x`, then the generic associative operator "lifts" no particular operator, and so `<...>` "wraps" the null operator to produce `<>`.

Comment: @chi Applicative is (just like monads famously are) a monoid in the appropriate category. https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4823 But I very much doubt that this was the justification behind the name decision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those names didn't come out of some overarching conceptual scheme. The best way to see that is by tracing their histories:

- McBride and Paterson's [*Applicative programming with effects*](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) uses an asterisk in a circle, ⊛, as the binary operator of `Applicative` (note that [there are theoretical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514013/2751851) to pick a `*`-like symbol that suggests a product). When [`Control.Applicative` made it to *base*](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/6.6/docs/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html) (that is, in *base*-2.1/GHC 6.6/October 2006), that became `<*>`, which is, as far as I can see, the closest ASCII approximation to that.
- The first version of `Control.Applicative` already featured `<$>`, and the final version of *Applicative programming with effects* I linked to above also mentions it (with the minor difference that the `<$>` there has an `Applicative` constraint). The point of picking a mashup of `$` and `<*>` as the `fmap` operator was presumably allowing us to write nice-looking applicative style expressions (`f <$> u <*> v <*> w`) that could be acceptable substitutes for the idiom brackets mentioned in that paper (which, rendered in ASCII, look like `[| f u v w |]`).
- The `Monoid` class came into being even earlier in the history of *base* (it already existed as of GHC 5.04.2, [in a `Control.Monad.Monoid` module](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.04.2/docs/html/base/Control.Monad.Monoid.html)); however, there wasn't an infix version of `mappend` in *base* until version 4.5 (GHC 7.4, early 2012). *Applicative programming with effects* also mentions monoids, and suggests a circled plus, ⊕, as a binary operator for `mappend`. As far as I can tell, the `<>` name was first suggested by Ross Paterson [in a Libraries mailing list thread from 2009](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2009-September/012540.html), and made its way into a [preexisting GHC proposal](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/3339), and presumably also to [Edward Kmett's *semigroups* package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups), whose `Data.Semigroup` module was eventually adopted by *base*. Paterson chose `<>` for it being a neutral name, which wouldn't suggest any specific monoid (see also: [*Why is the `mappend` infix alias `<>` instead of `+`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794894/2751851)).

Comment: @duplode : about '<*>' you can look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513329/does-in-have-a-special-meaning?noredirect=1#comment97734081_55513329

Comment: sorry to be more accurate the `*` in `<*>` is deliberate for example so why `<>` would be accidental ? it could have been something else than <> to avoid confusion with the set of  `<..>`

Comment: [1/2] @NicolasHenin (1) I meant to link to that other question of yours, but momentarily forgot about it. Now fixed. (2) When it comes to explaining why things are named as they are, I think it is important to look closely at their history. Perhaps Ed Kmett will show up here and correct me by saying he was thinking of `<*>` when he wrote the first version of *semigroups*, but right now I don't see evidence of there being a connection, except by an after-the-fact analogy (which is entirely fine, as long as we recognise it as being after-the-fact).

Comment: [2/2] @NicolasHenin It is important to be aware that *base*, or Haskell as a whole really, didn't come about in one fell swoop, but rather as the result of a long history of intertwining lines of inquiry and development.

Comment: @NicolasHenin Digging a little further, I found direct evidence for the origin of the `<>` name -- see my latest edit. Also, I have removed the XMonad `<+>` example, as including it would be anachronistic (its type originally was `ManageHook -> ManageHook -> ManageHook`; it only got generalised to the type of `mappend` with XMonad 0.10 from late 2011).

Comment: thanks for all the references and the explanations !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, `<..>` has no *general* meaning. However, there are certainly some connections with other operators, and most of the listed operators have some sort of mnemonic meaning:

- `$` is function application: `f $ x = f x`. `<$>` is clearly inspired by `$`: while `f $ x` applies `f` to `x`, `f <$> x` applies `f` to each element inside `x`. (Personally, `<$>` is my favourite operator.)
- The same relation holds between `&` and `<&>`.
- `<>` is the monoidal append operator: `"x" <> "y" <> "z"`, `Sum 1 <> Sum 2 <> Sum 3`. (**EDIT:** The following may or may not be correct - see edit below for more details.) As far as I'm aware those exact characters were just chosen to look nice, although there might be a connection with the use of `•` in mathematics to represent some arbitrary operator.
- (This was just speculation - see edit below for a more solid account.) <s>I think `<*>` was chosen to have a nice resonance with `<$>`: `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`. Additionally tuples are also known as product types (e.g. OCaml represents tuple types like `Int * String`, corresponding to Haskell `(Int, String)`), so there might be a resonance there with applying `f $ (x, y, z)` (not that anyone would ever do that instead of plain `f x y z` or `f (x, y, z)`).</s>

**EDIT:** Turns out that @chepner knew a bit more about the history than I do - thanks for commenting! In the [original paper introducing applicative functors](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf), the operator name `⊛` was used for the applicative operation; it was ASCII-fied as `<*>`. The same paper introduced `<$>`. Also `<>` *may* have been inspired by `<*>` as monoids and applicatives turn out to be related categorically. So amazingly enough, all the angled brackets did turn out to be related to each other! (Albeit very indirectly and tenuously...)

Comment: `<*>` is an ASCII representation of the symbol `⊛` used in [the paper that introduced applicative functors](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf). I'm not sure, but I think the same paper introduced `<$>` as an infix synonym for `fmap`. (It was defined in terms of `pure` and `⊛`, with the proof of its equivalence to `fmap` left unstated.)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that @chepner! Can I edit that in?

Comment: There's also the fact that applicative functors are a type of monoidal functor, which could suggest that `<>` is thus a monoid operator without any functorial overtones.

Comment: @chepner What's a monoidal functor?

Comment: Ugh, you had to ask :) Someone with a better grasp of category theory could give a better summary. A monoidal functor is just a functor between monoidal categories, and a monoidal category is a category `C` equipped with (wait for it) an associative bifunctor `foo :: C x C -> C` with an identity object in `C`.

Comment: Anyway, feel free to add any of this to your answer.

Comment: @bradrn : about monoidal functor : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702929/monoidal-functor-is-applicative-but-where-is-the-monoid-typeclass-in-the-definit